# Bootstrap-Datepicker Ajax+Json change date

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a Bootstrap-Datepicker and want to change the Date, using Ajax+Json, but it's not working, the Date changes format and when I select the calendar box it not assume the date in the Input field.
For the Datepicker Input I have this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Data de carregamento</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group input-medium date date-picker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="h_data" id="h_data" value="">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Datepicker initialization:

```
var handleDatePickers = function () {

        if (jQuery().datepicker) {
            $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                autoclose: true,
                language: 'pt'
            });
   }
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'php/cd_ener_ref.php?id='+id,
              type: 'post',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
              if (data.sucesso) {

                $.each(data, function (index, record) {
                  if ($.isNumeric(index)) { 

                    $('#h_data').val(record.h_data);
                    $('#h_data').datepicker("update", record.h_data);
                    $('#h_data').datepicker('refresh');
                  }
                })
              } 
              }
});
```

With this the Datepicker input is set to the Default Format and the calendar is not assuming the input date.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I gather your language is Portuguese so `if (data.sucesso)` is not a typo?

Comment: No, at this moment I get all the data correctly and with the line `$('#h_data').val(record.h_data);`  the value appear in the input field but if I press the calendar button it not appoint to the date that is on the input.